# Target everything except a certain class

Tags: css

```
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
font-family: arial;
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" height="300">
<tr style="font-weight: bold">
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    <th>Interest</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make CSS target everything EXCEPT a certain class?
I would like it to target every th tag EXCEPT a certain class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `:not`

```
li:not(.different) {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 2):

Using `:not` is certainly one alternative, but the classic CSS approach is to write two rules, general first, then specific.

```
th        { font-weight: bold; }
th.normal { font-weight: normal; }
```